# Android: Unhandled exception type IOException Error

Tags: java, android

I am total noob at Android dev. I am still learning, and I am on very first step of my app dev.

I have this code working and it runs fine or regular Java, now I am trying to implement to Android OS.

In my code where it says `TEST.openStream()` I get `Unhandled exception type IOException` error.

```
 package com.zv.android;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ZipActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            URL TEST = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(TEST.openStream()));

            String inputLine;
            int line=0;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                line++;
                       //System.out.println(line + "\t" + inputLine); 
            }
           // in.close();
        } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
            //Do something with the exception.
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Error message is simple: you need to catch the `IOException`, this because `URL.openStream()` is declared as

```
public final InputStream openStream() throws IOException
```

so by accepting the contract of the method you also accept the fact that you must handle this exception, this is how it works in Java. This is a *checked* exceptions, then it must be caught because this kind of exceptions represent situations that may arise and that your code must handle.

To catch it just add another case in your `try` statement:

```
try {
  ..
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  ..
}
catch (IOException e) {
  ..
}
```

Just as a final note: you don't need to catch it when you call the `openStream()` method, you could state that the method that calls `openStream()` will forward the exception to the caller but in the end of the call chain you will have to catch it in any case.

Answer (score 3):

Catch `IOException` also, like how you did for `MalformedURLException`  (or) declare method as throws `IOException`.

```
try {
            URL TEST = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(TEST.openStream()));

            String inputLine;
            int line=0;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                line++;
                       //System.out.println(line + "\t" + inputLine); 
            }
           // in.close();
        } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
            //Do something with the exception.
        } catch(IOException e2) {
            //Do something with the exception.
        }
```

`IOException` is checked exception, which either need to be catch (or) re-throw. See this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) for more information.

You need to catch IOException because [openStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) method may throw IOException in abnormal case.

Comment: Can you please explain me why we catch IOException as well ?

Answer (score 1):

```
TEST.openStream()
```

might throw an IOException which is a **checked exception** in java, thus you have to either **Handle** the IOException using **try/catch** blocks or **declare** IOException in your method signature using **throws** clause.

you have to handle IOException in your catch block .

```
 try {
            URL TEST = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(TEST.openStream()));
             //rest of your code
             } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
            //Do something with the exception.
        }

        catch(MalformedURLException e) {
        //Do something with the exception.
         }
         catch(IOException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Declaring IOException in your method signature:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) throws IOException {
```

in this case you dont wrap your code inside a try/catch, although i would strongly recommend always handle the exception using try/catch rather than declaring it using throws clause.